# Efficient nested loops with bootstrap resampling on DataFrame in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame with the following schema:

```
+--------------------+--------+-------+-------+-----------+--------------------+
|              userid|datadate|  runid|variant|device_type|          prediction|
+--------------------+--------+-------+-------+-----------+--------------------+
|0001d15b-e2da-4f4...|20220111|1196752|      1|     Mobile|  0.8827571312010658|
|00021723-2a0d-497...|20220111|1196752|      1|     Mobile| 0.30763173370229735|
|00021723-2a0d-497...|20220111|1196752|      0|     Mobile|  0.5336206154783815|
```

I would like to perform the following operation:
I want to do for each "runid", for each "device_type", some calculations with variant==1 and variant==0, including a resampling loop.
The ultimate goal is to store these calculations in another DF.

So in a naive approach the code would look like that:

```
for runid in df.select('runid').distinct().rdd.flatMap(list).collect():
    for device in ["Mobile","Desktop"]:
        a_variant = df.filter((df.runid  == runid) & (df.device_type  == device) & (df.variant  == 0))
        b_variant = df.filter((df.runid  == runid) & (df.device_type  == device) & (df.variant  == 1))

        ## do some more calculations here

        # bootstrap loop:
        for samp in range(100):
            sampled_vector_a = a_variant.select("prediction").sample(withReplacement = True, fraction = 1.0, seed = 123)
            sampled_vector_b = b_variant.select("prediction").sample(withReplacement = True, fraction = 1.0, seed = 123)

            ## do some more calculations here

      ## do some more calculations here
      ## store calculations in a new DataFrame
```

Currently the process is too slow.
How can I optimize this process by utilizing spark in the best way?
Thanks!

Comment: You're not really using Spark. Your for loop `for runid in df.select('runid').distinct().rdd.flatMap(list).collect()` iterates over a list and not a Spark dataframe. You can check that by `type(df.select('runid').distinct().rdd.flatMap(list).collect())` that's a list. This is because you are using `collect()`. What you need is to apply some _transformations_ to the dataframe, then Spark will do its optimizations.
Please provide a [mcve] for more help.

Comment: hey, thanks for the comment. I have edited the post to focus on the problem, I hope its more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to sample from each group in a dataframe after applying `groupBy`.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Demo").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,columns)
data = [["uid1","runid1",1,"Mobile",0.8],["uid2","runid1",1,"Mobile",0.3],
      ["uid3","runid1",0,"Mobile",0.5],["uid4","runid2",0,"Mobile",0.7],
      ["uid5","runid2",0,"Mobile",0.9]]
columns = ["userid","runid","variant","device_type","prediction"]

df.show()
# +------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
# |userid| runid|variant|device_type|prediction|
# +------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
# |  uid1|runid1|      1|     Mobile|       0.8|
# |  uid2|runid1|      1|     Mobile|       0.3|
# |  uid3|runid1|      0|     Mobile|       0.5|
# |  uid4|runid2|      0|     Mobile|       0.7|
# |  uid5|runid2|      0|     Mobile|       0.9|
# +------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

Define a sampling function that is going to be called by [`applyInPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas). The function `my_sample` extracts **one** sample for each input dataframe:

```
def my_sample(key, df):
    x = df.sample(n=1)
    return x
```

`applyInPandas` also needs a schema for its output, since it is returning the whole dataframe it will have the same fields as `df`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([StructField('userid', StringType()),
                     StructField('runid', StringType()),
                     StructField('variant', LongType()),
                     StructField('device_type', StringType()),
                     StructField('prediction', DoubleType())])
```

Just to check, try grouping the data, there are three groups:

```
df.groupby("runid", "device_type", "variant").mean("prediction").show()
# +------+-----------+-------+---------------+
# | runid|device_type|variant|avg(prediction)|
# +------+-----------+-------+---------------+
# |runid1|     Mobile|      0|            0.5|
# |runid1|     Mobile|      1|           0.55|
# |runid2|     Mobile|      0|            0.8|
# +------+-----------+-------+---------------+
```

Now apply `my_sample` to each group using [`applyInPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas):

```
df.groupby("runid","device_type","variant").applyInPandas(my_sample, schema=schema).show()
# +------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
# |userid| runid|variant|device_type|prediction|
# +------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
# |  uid3|runid1|      0|     Mobile|       0.5|
# |  uid2|runid1|      1|     Mobile|       0.3|
# |  uid4|runid2|      0|     Mobile|       0.7|
# +------+------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

Note: I used `applyInPandas` since [`pyspark.sql.GroupedData.apply.html`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.apply.html) is deprecated